# Postfix: set privileges for a certain command pipe alias

Tags: linux, permissions, pipe, alias, postfix-mta

I'm trying to set up an alias that pipes incoming mail for a command in Postfix. So I have something like this in my `/etc/aliases`:

```
myuser: "|/usr/bin/command --parameter1 --parameter2"
```

The problem is that Postfix executes `/usr/bin/command` as user `nobody:nogroup`. According to [this description](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#default_privs) it can be changed, but not for a single alias. So the question is how to set the user for a certain alias? Setting `nobody:nogroup` for a directory `/usr/bin/command` should operate is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `/usr/bin/command` with `/usr/bin/sudo -u <user> /usr/bin/command` and configure `sudo` to allow `nobody` to execute this command.

**[EDIT]** There are two solutions for your problem:

1. Make all necessary files read/writable for `nobody:nogroup`
2. Change the user (either with a [suid script](http://www.codecoffee.com/tipsforlinux/articles/028.html) or `su`/`sudo`).

If you don't like either, then there is no solution for your problem. You can't do it in `aliases(5)` because the format doesn't support this (other programs read this file as well, so postfix can't change the syntax).

You could use `default_privs` but that would change the user for all external commands and you don't want that (huge security risk).

Comment: I've thought about it but it appears to me a very brute solution. Not too far from chown nobody:nogroup to the directory I need. Is that really the common way to change owner for an alias command in Postfix?

Comment: @FmyOen: Linux doesn't offer any other ways to solve this. `sudo` at least restricts this operation; when you `chown` the files, anyone can read (and maybe even change) them.

Comment: Maybe we can deal with the problem using some Postfix settings? I mean not by specifying WHICH commands Postfix should execute, but HOW should it do it.

Comment: Maybe but internally, Postfix calls `sudo` (or the kernel API which `sudo` uses).

Comment: I just checked the documentation. You can either change the user for all commands via `default_privs` (not recommended) or you can use `sudo` in `aliases(5)`. The reason for this is that the format of `aliases(5)` is a standard and postfix can't change/influence this (all other programs reading the file would break).

Comment: actually you can simply [create a secondary](https://serverfault.com/a/517805/366157) `aliases` that is owned by the wanted user. Once registered in `main.cf`, all piped commands run as the user that is the owner of the `aliases.db` file, of which you can have many in a comma-seperated-list for `alias_database`/`alias_maps`

Comment: @Hashbrown Can you please convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: `Closed. This question is off-topic. It is not currently accepting answers.` :(